# In C programming, L-value required is a semantic error or syntax error?

Tags: c, syntax-error, language-lawyer, lvalue

```
1. int main(void) 
2. { 
3.   int a =5, b = 6, c; 
4.   a + b = c; // lvalue required error
5.   2 = a ;     //lvalue required error
6. }
```

4th and 5th lines of code are considered as a syntax error or semantic error?
According to me, these lines should throw the syntax error but I found that Context Free Grammar can generate them.

Comment: May I know the reason for downvotes. So that I can improve the post.

Comment: The syntax of your code is just wrong.  Everything on the right of the equals operator are always assigned to the variable on the left of the operator.

Comment: I know that sir and those 2 lines are the points of my doubt that if I write them in the opposite order than which error does the compiler throw.

Comment: I've added the "language-lawyer" tag to the question, which can be used to inform that you are interested in the language specification and grammar, rather than practical use. Some trigger-happy people might have down-voted because they think you are asking why the code doesn't compile.

Comment: (or it could have to do with the phase of the moon... sometimes there is no good reason)

Comment: Thanks for adding it. People just start downvoting before even reading the complete question. :)

Comment: It always helps to write more prose into your question

Comment: It should be added that the distinction of syntax and non-syntax error is rather vague outside language-lawyering and/or compiler generation and such...

Comment: I will take care of it from now onwards. :)

Comment: You can generate line 5, certainly. Perhaps you could show the derivation of line 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said it, it is a semantic error / constraints violation.

From [C11 6.5.16p2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16p2)

> **Constraints**
>
> 2. An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

The C syntax description is not enough to discern lvalues from non-lvalues.

The actual production where the assignment operator appears is [C11 6.5.16p1](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16p1):

```
unary-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression
```

And `unary-expression` includes, among everything else, the possibility of having any expression in parentheses.

So a simple parser following the grammar indeed is going to generate proper parse trees for these invalid expressions, and further analysis is required to see whether or not they match the constraints in the standard.

Even the simplest cases, like

```
foo = 5;
```

might or might not be valid - depending on whether or not `foo` is a modifiable lvalue **and** whether `5` is assignable to a modifiable value of type of `foo` without a cast...

---

**HOWEVER**, there is this one small thing. The production

```
unary-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression
```

allows only an unary exception on the left-hand side. It does not allow for `a + b` to appear on LHS unparenthesized! There seems to be something fishy going on with all the C compilers I've tried (GCC, MSVC, clang). It can be that all of them use the C++ grammar and then weed out the impossibilities. In C++,

```
a + b
```

could return a mutable reference, and hence should be allowed to appear on the left-hand side.

Comment: It helped me. Thank you so much for this answer.

Comment: How do you derive `a + b = c` from that production? `a + b` is certainly not a `unary-expression`. Similarly `b = c` is not a `multiplicative-expression`, so it cannot be an operator of `+`. It's true that in the the general case, the provided BNF grammar is not sufficient  to fully express that constraint. For example, `(a + b) = c` can be derived from the grammar but violates the constraint. But `a + b = c` does violate the grammar. So *some* of them are syntactic.

Comment: ... that is, if you take a very rigid and possibly incorrect view of what syntactic means in this context. Personally, I think that various constraints are syntactic. Some are even lexical, eg. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4p2

Comment: @rici hmm, you might be correct. It requires an addition to this post.